# Что такое сборка в C#

Tags: c#, сборка

Я определил модификатор доступа private protected, пишется, что он будет доступен в данной сборке, но что имеется в виду под словом "сборка"?

Comment: Может internal protected?

Comment: это тот файл что генерирует компилятор dll/exe https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если глобально, то сборка - это структурная единица в .NET . Может быть в виде exe или dll файлов. Т.е., например, ваша .NET Framework Class Library после билда будет сборкой.
По поводу модификатора доступа. Рассмотрим обе части этого составного модификатора доступа:

1. `private` - это закрытый класс или член класса. Доступа извне к нему нет. Т.е., если метод имеет модификатор `private` , то использовать его можно только в пределах класса, в котором он определён.
2. `protected` - такой член класса доступен только в пределах класса и во наследниках данного класса. Обратите внимание, что наследники могут располагаться и в других сборках.

`private protected` - такой член класса доступен внутри данного класса, а также в классах, которые являются наследниками этого класса **И** находятся с ним в одной сборке.

Более наглядно.

ClassLibrary - Сторонняя библиотека (одна сборка)
ConsoleApp1 - Консольное приложение (другая сборка)

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Helper
    {
        private protected void Convert()
        {
            // logic
        }
    }
}

namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class JsonHelper : Helper
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            //доступ есть
            Convert();
        }
    }
}
 
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class XmlHelper : Helper
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            // доступа нет
            Convert();
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. как мы видим Helper.Convert будет доступен внутри Helper и внутри JsonHelper. Т.к. JsonHelper является наследником и определён в одной сборке.

Внутри XmlHelper метод Helper.Convert уже будет недоступным. Хотя XmlHelper и наследник Helper'а, но он стоит в другой сборке.